# How do I achieve similar functionality to DbSet.AddOrUpdate?

Tags: .net

I need to do something very similar to DbSet.AddOrUpdate, i.e. passing an expression and an array into a method and then finding the value of the field as defined by the expression for each item in the array.

Doesn't look like MS have published the source code for AddOrUpdate (which is a shame) hence I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers.

Cheers Mike

Comment: Where do you need it and for what? Are you using entity framework or ADO.NET or what else?

Comment: I want to record the date that a record was written into the Db by the seeding routine. I will be using it in the Seeding routine in order to see if each record in the seeding data array already exists in the Db and if does then I will change one of the fields in the record in the array to the relevant value in the Db. Hope that makes sense.